# How can I get the callers/callees information from Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

[image]

Is it possible for me to get the callers/callees information, like the picture above,from Xcode? And if yes, how?

Comment: I don't understand the question. This screenshot is from Xcode... Are you asking how to do that?

Comment: I want to know how can I extract these information into a file?The output file may like this:
ViewController::viewDidLoad
Callees
 -[UIViewController viewDidLoad]
Callers
 //other methods